# Volume rendering is more transparent from one direction that another

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, volume-rendering, raymarching

I'm trying to get my head around volume rendering using three.js and ray marching GLSL. I've got some data I synthesised from a numpy array.

The cube of data being rendered is more opaque on one side, graduating to being transparent on the other side - like this (ignore the wire frame, that's just for a bit of orientation)
[image]

however, when you look at the cube from the more transparent end, the transparency seems to "block out" the less transparent end (hope that makes sense). Like this:
[image]

I don't know if this is related, but I also have a problem that when the camera is slightly inside the cube, it stops rendering properly. It cuts off the bit nearest to the camera, like this:
[image]
Is this a related issue, or is it just a limitation of the method.

The code is here 
https://github.com/niallrobinson/test-volume-rendering/blob/master/viewer.htmlhttps://github.com/niallrobinson/test-volume-rendering/blob/master/viewer.js
https://github.com/niallrobinson/test-volume-rendering/blob/master/viewer.html

and the second pass shaders look like this:

```
<script id="vertexShaderFirstPass" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;
    void main(){
        //Set the world space coordinates of the back faces vertices as output.
        worldSpaceCoords = position + vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5); //move it from [-0.5;0.5] to [0,1]
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShaderFirstPass" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;
    void main(){
        //The fragment's world space coordinates as fragment output.
        gl_FragColor = vec4( worldSpaceCoords.x , worldSpaceCoords.y, worldSpaceCoords.z, 1 );
    }
</script>


<!-- second pass shaders -->
<script id="vertexShaderSecondPass" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;
    varying vec4 projectedCoords;

    void main()
    {
        worldSpaceCoords = (modelMatrix * vec4(position + vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 1.0 )).xyz;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix *  modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        projectedCoords =  projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    }
</script>

<script id="fragmentShaderSecondPass" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying vec3 worldSpaceCoords;
    varying vec4 projectedCoords;

    uniform sampler2D firstPassTexture, dataTexture; //i.e. tex and cubeTex
    uniform float steps;
    uniform float alphaCorrection;
    const int MAX_STEPS = 512;

    vec3 dataDims = vec3(4, 4, 4);

    vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 pos) {
        // pos is in UV coords i.e. 0->1. We also want to interrogate out texture in the range 0->1
        // however, our 3D dimensions are conceptually 4,4,4
        float nTiles = dataDims.z;
        float tileWidth = 1.0 / nTiles;
        float p = pos.y * tileWidth + pos.x / nTiles;
        float q = pos.z;

        lowp vec4 sample = texture2D(tex, vec2(p, q)); //I think this fn might convert from 255 range to 0->1 range
        vec4 returnSample = vec4(0.7, 0., 0., sample.x * alphaCorrection); // alpha is 255 in png so overwrite
        return returnSample;
    }

    // max 2d size is 4096 x 4096

    void main( void ) {
        //Transform the coordinates it from [-1;1] to [0;1]
        vec2 firstPassTexCoord = vec2(((projectedCoords.x / projectedCoords.w) + 1.0 ) / 2.0,
                        ((projectedCoords.y / projectedCoords.w) + 1.0 ) / 2.0 );

        //The back position is the world space position stored in the texture.
        vec3 backPos = texture2D(firstPassTexture, firstPassTexCoord).xyz;

        //The front position is the world space position of the second render pass.
        vec3 frontPos = worldSpaceCoords;

        //The direction from the front position to back position.
        vec3 dir = backPos - frontPos;

        float rayLength = length(dir);

        //Calculate how long to increment in each step.
        float delta = 1.0 / steps;

        //The increment in each direction for each step.
        vec3 deltaDirection = normalize(dir) * delta;
        float deltaDirectionLength = length(deltaDirection);

        //Start the ray casting from the front position.
        vec3 currentPosition = frontPos;

        //The color accumulator.
        vec4 accumulatedColor = vec4(0.0);

        //The alpha value accumulated so far.
        float accumulatedAlpha = 0.0;

        //How long has the ray travelled so far.
        float accumulatedLength = 0.0;

        //vec4 dataSample;
        vec4 dataSample;

        float alphaSample;

        //Perform the ray marching iterations
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++){
            //Get the voxel intensity value from the 3D texture.    
            dataSample = sampleAs3DTexture(dataTexture, currentPosition);

            //Allow the alpha correction customization
            alphaSample = dataSample.a;

            //Perform the composition.
            accumulatedColor += (1.0 - accumulatedAlpha) * dataSample * alphaSample;
            //accumulatedColor += dataSample;

            //Store the alpha accumulated so far.
            accumulatedAlpha += alphaSample;

            //Advance the ray.
            currentPosition += deltaDirection;
            accumulatedLength += deltaDirectionLength;

            //If the length traversed is more than the ray length, or if the alpha accumulated reaches 1.0 then exit.
            if(accumulatedLength >= rayLength || accumulatedAlpha >= 1.0 )
                break;
        }
        gl_FragColor = accumulatedColor;
    }

</script>
```

Thanks in advance everyone

**EDIT:** After a bit of experimentation, it seems that the problem is that only the outside of the cube is being rendered. If I put a blob of data in the middle of the cube, you don't see anything.

**EDIT:** Infact, its only rendering data on the frontside surface. If I reverse the ray marching direction (i.e. change it to towards the camera), you can only view it on the backside surface

Comment: Your 3rd picture is simply the near plane on the camera. You can minimize the effect by using a smaller number in your camera definition, but don't make it too small or you'll get strange artifacts because of floating point precision errors.

Comment: thanks - that has made that clipping thing go away - good call. btw note the edit on the OP about only rendering the outside of the cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think its sorted! The data returned from the tex lookup was a vec4. That was then being used to increment `accumulatedColor`. I changed `accumulatedColor` to a vec3 and only incremented it by `.xyz` and that seemed to do the trick

Thanks to everyone who took a look